# ASP.NET Identity: Null Object Reference in AddUserAndRole

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership

I am attempting to move legacy ASP.NET WebSite code to WebApp.  In the user membership portion, I am following the process laid out here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/membership-and-administration

However, a null object exception occurs at this line:

```
if (!userMgr.IsInRole(userMgr.FindByEmail("myEmail").Id, "myRole"))
```

Here is the stack trace:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>
> HResult=-2147467261
>
> Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source=newWebApp
>
> StackTrace:
>          at newWebApp.Logic.RoleActions.AddUserAndRole() in App\newWebApp\Logic\RoleActions.cs:line 48
>          at newWebApp.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because the username had an invalid character.  In this case, the username had a dash ("-") causing an invalid member creation.  Removing invalid characters fixed the issue.